# Create Event that occurs once a day at specific time

Tags: c#

I know I have seen an answer to this somewhere, but have been able to find it.

Basically I have an application where the user can select a time of day and the application will run. It's a type of backup application.

I am trying to steer clear of scheduled tasks, so with that in mind I am using a timer. The problem i am having is being able to use standard time format IE : hh:mm and convert that to milliseconds for the timer. or better put I guess:

have the application identify the user selected time.
count the time between the current time and the selected time for the first elapsed_event
then create a timer after the event occurs that runs at the user selected time of day.

Again I remember seeing something either on here or on another site that had an excellent example... but i can't find it anywhere.

I am using winforms C# in Visual Studio 2012

```
timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = inter * 1000 * 60;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run once a day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280566/run-once-a-day)

Comment: While it's certainly possible to do what you are asking, there's rarely a good reason to do so. Handling absolute schedules at high intervals (once a day, once an hour) is better managed by an external/lower-level service. Operating at this level reduces your solution's impact on the system load when otherwise necessary as the OS already implies such behavior/overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a [scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678.aspx) for executing task at a particular time of the day.

From the task you can execute a c# application.

---

If you donot want to use scheduled task, you can do following
1. Set the interval to the difference in specific time and current time
2. When timer is fired first time, set the interval to 86400 sec.

```
var time = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHour(16).AddMinute(40)// if timer it to be executed at 16:40
var timespan = time - DateTime.Now;
var interval = timespan.TotalSeconds;
if (interval < 0) interval = interval + 86400;
```

In `timer1_Elapsed`

```
if (timer1.Interval != 86400) timer1.Inverval = 86400
```

Comment: don't want to use scheduled tasks as stated above