# Execute Code daily in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I have Web application. I need to check for late orders every day. I search for the best way to do that ? but I still cant find it ? Is WCF is helpful ? or there are another technology to do that ?

Comment: What should happen when there are late orders?

Comment: Send Email for spacific users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx) and configure a Timer to execute following a period specified. In the scope of this timer executing by the Windows Service you could add your routine to call another service to perform something.

Comment: How can add  Windows Service Application to my Web app

Comment: You cannot. It is a separated application that will be instaled on windows and execute as a windows application, but it is a windows service. If you have permission to do it, I think it is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

In the `global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        InitializeLateOrdersChecker();
    }

    private void InitializeLateOrdersChecker()
    {
        // code for your timer. The ideal is running it every 60 seconds or so.
    }
}
```

A question (and answer) for the timer part:

[Run once a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280566/run-once-a-day)

Comment: Alexandre, it will execute only when the application starts. If you restart your application everyday ok, but it is not definitely a good approach!.

Comment: It will only run once if you don't set a looped timer.