# timer inside a thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer

how to start a forms.timer inside a simple thread,i have a problem
 where i need to start a timer inside a thread,how can i do that

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative would be to use the [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(VS.71).aspx) class that doesn't need a message loop and look like the Windows forms one or you could directly use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) (If you need to know all the differences between the two classes there is [a blog post with all the details](http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/SystemWindowsFormsTimerVsSystemThreadingTimerVsSystemTimersTimer.aspx)) :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (new Timer(state => Console.WriteLine(state), "Hi!", 0, 5 * 1000))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to work it need a message loop, you could start one in a thread using `Application.Run` either [the parameter-less one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) or [the one taking an `ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx) for better lifetime control.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var timer = new Timer();
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
            if (DateTime.Now - startTime > new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0))
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        };
        timer.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use threading you really want to use System.Threading.Timer.

See this question for more details: [Is there a timer class in C# that isn't in the Windows.Forms namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169332/is-there-a-timer-class-in-c-that-isnt-in-the-windows-forms-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) says:

*This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must be used in a window.*

Use something like Thread.Sleep instead.